# thread execution : how to ensure the systematic starting of thread

Tags: linux-kernel, pthreads, scheduler

I am seeing different ways of starting threads in ubuntu and in other linux platform.

```
pthread_create ( &thread1, NULL, (void *) &myfun1, (void *) msg1);
pthread_create ( &thread2, NULL, (void *) &myfun2, (void *) msg2);
pthread_create ( &thread3, NULL, (void *) &myfun3, (void *) msg3);
pthread_create ( &thread4, NULL, (void *) &myfun4, (void *) msg4);
```

In the above case of ubuntu , first the thread4 is starting while in case of other linux os it's the thread1. When I checked reason, seems to be because of **scheduling policies**(correct me if i am wrong).

1. In these cases how to ensure that the always the first thread (thread1) executes first despite of different linux flavours.
2. /*Generic query*/, does the scheduling policy does not depend upon kernel ? Because two different types of thread execution is seen in the different linux flavours.

Comment: It lies in the nature of asynchronism that is's asynchon. Without addtional synchonisation mechanics (mutexes/conditions) you cannot predict the order of when the threads are running (or even start).

Comment: ok synch we can added after thread starts.. but before creation of thread how to ensure ?

Comment: You have to assume that any thread at any time can be suspended to give processing time to a different thread. So, if you managed to start them in a reliable order, it still wouldn't give you anything. I think that whatever you think you could achieve is an illusion and you should instead describe what your actual problem is. Also, you seem to target so C-ish language, but which one exactly is that? While you're at it, add "multithreading" to the list of tags.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code that makes thread 1 start before the other thread execute the tasks:

```
Mutex mutex = ... /* static init here */
Condition cond = ... /* static init here */

boolean first_thread_running = false;

thread1
{
  mutex_lock

  first_thread_running = true;
  cond_signal

  mutex_unlock

  /* do things */
}

thread<N> /* with <N> = {2, 3, 4} */
{
  mutex_lock

  while (not first_thread_running)
    cond_wait

  mutex_unlock

  /* thread1 definitly runs now */

  /* do things */
}    


main
{
  /* The order of the following statements does not matter, thread 1
     will always be started before the other threads "do their things". */

  thread4_create
  thread2_create
  thread1_create
  thread3_create

  ...
```

Comment: Well i was expecting there might be some other way except locking mechanism, thanks for the suggestion